# GNUplot $GDFONTPATH and symbol fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, gnuplot, symbols

I'm still trying to get a symbol font called Moon Phases to function in my PDF output, and ran across this SO thread:

> [How do I access various true type fonts through gnuplot with png terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376720/how-do-i-access-various-true-type-fonts-through-gnuplot-with-png-terminal/1426123)

Could someone please tell me what is meant by:

> Don't forget to source the .profilefile
>   at the end of the thread?

OSX 10.6.8
GNUplot 4.6.3

Comment: What is meant there is that after you create the file /Users/username/.profile, you need to source it either with the command `source /Users/username/.profile` or by restarting your terminal.

Comment: GDFONTPATH won't have any effect on pdf output.  It only effects the terminals using `libgd` which are the old `png`, `jpeg` and `gif` terminals.

Comment: Thanks gents. Any further ideas about how to access that font in pdfcairo output? I've read and tried all the man pages till I'm blue in the face.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible to embed a font in a pdf using gnuplot and `pdfcairo`.  I'm pretty sure you can embed a font in a postscript which you could then convert to a pdf pretty easily I would think ... However, I've never done it.  Perhaps @andyras has?  (This seems like it might be a little more up his ally)

Comment: Yes, I you can use the `fontfile '/path/to/font/file'` option to the `set terminal postscript` command to embed a font file into an eps, then use any number of utilities (`epstopdf`, `eps2pdf`, `convert`...) to make a .pdf.

Comment: @andyras I'll go back and try the eps again, especially as I didn't know about the secondary processing step to output PDF. Been hoping against hope to make it a one-step output, especially as GNUplot on OSX finds that font in the Aqua terminal and for SVG output. This is way above my paygrade and the help from you gents is much appreciated.

Comment: @andyras I'll go back and try the eps again, especially as I didn't know about the secondary processing step to output PDF. Been hoping against hope to make it a one-step output, especially as GNUplot on OSX finds that font in the Aqua terminal and for SVG output; I have tried enabling .ttf, .otf, .pda and ps versions of that font in Font Book and it doesn't help. This is way above my paygrade and the help from you gents is much appreciated.

Comment: To make it a little bit more one-step you can call the eps to pdf conversion command from within gnuplot, with a line something like `!sleep 1; epstopdf myoutput.eps` at the end of your script.  The `sleep 1` is because (in my experience) sometimes gnuplot can't find the file it just made for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

The .profile is only loaded by your shell on startup, so when you start the Terminal App.

If you want to reload it without restarting your shell/Terminal session you can source it by typing

```
source ~/.profile
```

This only has to be done on shells/Terminal sessions that have been started before the changes were made to the file.

Comment: I suppose this answers OP's *explicit* question, but it won't solve the *actual* problem unfortunately.